# Java is not recognized in MacOs Ventura 13.5

Tags: java, macos, macos-ventura

I got a MacBook Air M2 to develop Flutter applications. When I opened a project for the very first time, it asks me to install gradle extensions, but now when I open a project, Visual Studio Code shows me:

```bash
No Java executable found, please consider to configure your 'java.jdt.ls.java.home' setting or set JAVA_HOME in your path or put a Java executable in your path.
```

I tried to use `java --version` to see if I had java in my machine. The command show:

```bash
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
```

But if I use the next command: `which java`, it shows `/usr/bin/java`. So, Can I consider that I have at least one java version?

What should I do? Do I need configure the current java in my machine as a default or install a new java? Could be problems if I install a new version since I already have one installed?

Comment: My guess is that if you run `/usr/bin/java --version` directly you'll get that same string and that executable is just a placeholder.

Comment: I tried that command and show "the operation couldn't...". What should I do then?

Comment: @Freeman your example is not correct. JAVA_HOME should point to the top directory of a Java distribution. `/usr/bin/java` is an executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## *SDKMAN!*

> What should I do?

Delete whatever JDKs you already downloaded and installed.

Install [SDKMAN!](https://sdkman.io/). This clever collection of [shell scripts](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script) makes easy work of installing software kits such as a [JDK](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit).

At the console such as Terminal.app, execute:

```bash
sdk list java
```

From the list of JDK products known to SDKMAN!, choose which version of which product you want. Be sure to choose a vendor and product whose legal terms you find agreeable.

Copy the exact name of your choice. Type `Q` to quit the list.

Then paste the copied name into the following line of your console, and execute.

```bash
sdk install java paste-product-name-here
```

Wait a few minutes as your desired JDK product downloads and installed.

Eventually SDKMAN! prompts you to ask if you want to make this JDK the default. Answer `Y` for “yes”.

✔️ Easy-peasy, done.

Verify by doing these two tasks:

```bash
sdk list java
```

You should see an indicator of which JDK product(s) you have installed.

```bash
java --version
```

You should get a report of the default JDK product’s version number.

SDKMAN! can just as easily:

- Install later versions
- Uninstall older JDKs no longer needed.
- Mark a different JDK as default.

See the website for easy instructions.